# Question regarding independent (Bernoulli) trials: rolling a die 10 times and defining success as rolling a 1 or a 6.

Tags: probability, independence, bernoulli-distribution

I just want to make sure that the scenario I'm describing is indeed a Bernoulli trial type of experiment. Here is the set up and query regarding the set up:
A six-sided die is rolled 10 times. What is the probability that a 1 or a 6 is rolled exactly two times? (This is not to be understood as a 6 being rolled twice or a 1 being rolled twice, but either of the two being rolled twice, e.g. 1...1..., 1...6..., 6...1..., 6...6...). We can define the event $A=\{ 1,6 \}$ and $A^{c}= \{ 2,3,4,5 \}$.

I'm inclined to see this as a Bernoulli trial with $p= P(A)=1/3$ and $n=10$, and the answer being $\binom{10}{2}p^{2}(1-p)^{8}$. One just can think of an analogous scenario of selecting 10 balls (with replacement) from an urn containing 2 black marbles and 4 white marbles (where we identify 1 and 6 with black marbles and other numbers with white marbles), and asking for the probability of selecting 3 black marbles among the 10 chosen.

It may seem odd that we're effectively counting the four classes (each class can occur $4^{8}$ ways) of events, e.g. $1---6-----$ and $6---1-----$ and $1---1-----$ and $6---6-----$ as a *single* Bernoulli outcome, i.e. $SFFFSFFFFF$, but I'm *almost* (hence the question) sure that this still satisfies the criteria for a Bernoulli trial type of experiment, since the entire sample space is "flattened" in an analogous manner.

Comment: Yes though some might say the plural of *Bernoulli* is *binomial*

Comment: Your analysis and approach are both correct and there should be nothing concerning about it.  There is no reason to keep track of irrelevant information if it doesn't change the final result and it is never referenced again.  Of course, if you insisted, you could have also seen the calculation as $\dfrac{\binom{10}{2}2^2\cdot 4^8}{6^{10}}$ where we kept track of all die results... but this equals what you got.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the answer.